# how to inner join from different databases SQL server and Sqlite in python?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlite

I have a sql server data base and in memory sqlite table, how can I inner join between these DB  using python?!
The number of records is too much, and i don't want to keep this data in my codes

Comment: You can not join between different databases.

Comment: Use pandas to load the data in to data frames and join them